# Telethon get msg sender name

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I'm using Telethon in my python project to get msg from a specific group:

```
full_msg_list = self.client.get_messages(GROUP_ID, limit=200)
```

When I iterate the `full_msg_list` every msg object as `sender_id` that is a number but i want to get the username of the sender and not his id.

Any suggestions on how to get the user name?

Comment: Can't you just get the username from the id.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`result = (await message.get_sender()).username`

where `message` is the message returned by the iteration of `full_msg_list`

Comment: Hey @TheKill-996 How would you get the user_id of the sender of a specific msg and also the group where the msg was posted in? In python btw...thanks a bunch!